# Set a boolean flag in java through javascript

Tags: java, javascript

Hi I am detecting browser in javascript and for safari browser I have to download the audio file whereas for every other browser I have to play audio.Thus my code is detecting browser safari correctly but I am stuck with how to show my server that safari is browser.
Thus is there anyway through which I can set some boolean flag in server through javascript.
My server code is in java.

for example:

```
var detector=code...(This code detects browser as safari)

if(detector)
{
    code to set flag server side which knows that the browser is 
    safari and have to download captcha.
}
```

Comment: What are you sending to the server in the non-Safari cases? Assuming you're sending an HTTP request which your Java code is receiving, it sounds like you just need to add a flag as either request payload or query parameter.

Comment: Hi I am using httpheader but since I have to download for safari I am using if(downlaod){.header("Content_Disposition", "attachment; filename=xyz"} but I am not getting how the download will be set through javascript

Comment: That's what you're doing on the server side. What are you doing in the browser in the non-download case? What request are you sending up?

Comment: I am playing audio by adding .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, method.length).build(); Thus I want to set download flag to give information to server that the flag is set and have to download audio or to just play audio

Comment: Presumably you are doing this while constructing an HTTP response. What are you responding TO?

Comment: Responding to request made by client. I dint get your question

Answer (score 2):

> how to show my server that safari is browser

This is why the `User-Agent` HTTP request header exists. The web browser already tells the server which browser it is. You don't need to write javascript to do that.

Recommanded reading:

- [Mozilla: "Browser detection using the user agent"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)
- [RFC 2616: "HTTP/1.1", section 14.43: "User-Agent"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43)
- [Wikipedia: "User agent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)
- [Java Servlet API: HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String))

Comment: Heh. Yes; I was missing forest for trees there and not considering that OP was asking the wrong question in the first place.

Comment: User-Agent: CERN-LineMode/2.15 libwww/2.17b3 What is CERN-LineMode/2.15 libwww/2.17b3? So you are saying that I dont have to do anything? Is there any package to import for user agent

Comment: It's an example of a user agent string, albeit a very old one (since that spec is from 1999).

Comment: You just need to get the `User-Agent` header from the HTTP request. If you're using servlets, call [request.getHeader("User-Agent")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)). If not, or if you're using some other library on top of the servlet container, I'd need to know that to help.

Comment: I am using javax.ws.rs.core.HTTPHeaders Response QueryParam

Comment: I'm unfamiliar, but it certainly looks like that API gives you access to request headers.

Comment: So what should I do now? As in how to use user agent

Comment: I haven't used it, but [UADetector](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/) looks like it might be good for this.